# Error 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat' in gRPC Spring Boot Client

Tags: spring-boot, grpc, grpc-java

I am getting below error while starting spring boot grpc client application. Getting this error within *GrpcClientBeanPostProcessor* processing

> org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext WARN Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Below are the dependencies:

```
<java.version>1.8</java.version>
<grpc.version>1.47.0</grpc.version>
<protoc.version>3.5.1</protoc.version>
<protobuf-maven-plugin.version>0.6.1</protobuf-maven-plugin.version>

-------

<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.6.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

-------
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.devh</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-client-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-protobuf</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>grpc-stub</artifactId>
            <version>${grpc.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java-util</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to have guava latest for resolving this. Working fine with the below.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
   <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
   <version>23.6-jre</version>
</dependency>
```